# Calculate Actual time spent on an app using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have to create a functionality where I need to capture the total time spent on a module in the application. Now we have 5 modules and each module has different pages and flows.

Say, we have a module to capture **customer information**. So the **total time spent** on this module would be the sum of time spent on each page (basic information, address details, education background, etc) in this flow.

We also need to calculate the **time for sub-modules**. For example, address details have a current and permanent address. In that case, we need to know the time spent on each of these pages and the total time should be assigned to the time spent in address details

Users can also **close the page** midway or **go back to the previous page**, and in that case, the time for that particular page should be started or resumed.

Would like to know how can I go about this and how the backend APIs should be designed for this as I am not able to wrap my head around this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend to only send basic events to some backend service and do all of the calculations there. This is the typical analytics use case and there's tons of libraries and cloud service that do this. As long as the frontend is sending accurate events (navigation changed, closing page, etc.) this is better off on the backend side.

Comment: @timotgl yes but we need to send the some payload as well right so that backend can identify which module or page we are on?

Comment: Yes you would send the name of the current route/page and any other parameters that are relevant for analytical insights. My recommendation is to leverage one of the SAAS solutions that already do "time spent on page x" calculations and tons of other statistics for you.

Comment: @timotgl Still confused about how the payload should look as it is not only about the current route but modules as well if you see my post. Example - if I capture the time of permanent and current address, how will I identify that those two belong to address details?

Comment: You'd come up with some sort of routing scheme for them like calling the pages `/address-details/permanent` and `/address-details/current`. On the analytics backend, you'd sum up the time spent on them by using a rule like "time spent on pages starting with `address-details/`". How it works in detail depends on the chosen backend solution. But this is a very common thing for marketing and product people to want to know, so there are solutions for them to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a combination of React state and built-in Date object.

For each page in a module or sub-module, create a state variable to store the time spent on that page

```
const [timeSpentOnPage, setTimeSpentOnPage] = useState(0); // in milliseconds
```

useEffect hook to start a timer for each page as soon as it is rendered

```
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    setTimeSpentOnPage(prevTime => prevTime + 1000); // increment by 1 second
  }, 1000); // every 1 second
  return () => clearInterval(intervalId); // cleanup
}, []); // run only once on mount
```

To handle cases where the user navigates away from the page and comes back later, you could store the timestamp when the user leaves the page in local storage

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleUnload = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('pageLeaveTime', new Date().getTime());
  };
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleUnload); // cleanup
}, []);
```

When the user returns to the page, you could retrieve the previous leave time from local storage and resume the timer from that point

```
useEffect(() => {
  const pageLeaveTime = localStorage.getItem('pageLeaveTime');
  if (pageLeaveTime) {
    const timeSpentSoFar = new Date().getTime() - Number(pageLeaveTime);
    setTimeSpentOnPage(timeSpentSoFar);
  }
}, []);
```

To calculate the total time spent on a module or sub-module, you could use another state variable to store the cumulative time spent across all its pages

```
const [totalTimeSpent, setTotalTimeSpent] = useState(0); // in milliseconds
```

Whenever the user completes a page and moves on to the next one or closes the module, you could add the time spent on that page to the cumulative time for the module

```
const handlePageCompletion = () => {
  setTotalTimeSpent(prevTime => prevTime + timeSpentOnPage);
  localStorage.removeItem('pageLeaveTime');
  setTimeSpentOnPage(0);
};

const handleModuleClose = () => {
  setTotalModuleTime(prevTime => prevTime + totalTimeSpent);
  setTotalTimeSpent(0);
};
```

Comment: I will try this approach. Just one more doubt. How should I design the backend API for this as this information needs to be stored in the backend?

Comment: Seems a good answer to me, just would say that even it might work, it looks a bit risky to me the setStates in handleTimeSpent and handleModuleClose. As you are reseting the totalTimeSpent and setTimeSpentOnPage while using this value to setModuleTime. As setState is asynchronous, I think it is not very safe doing this.

Comment: @pepinillo6969 what do you think would be the better approach then in that case?

Comment: sure, @pepinillo6969 it's just simple example/guide, the actual implementation needs to be improved, of course. (btw, it will work)

Comment: @MohitChauhan do you have endpoints for this? or you need to design it by yourself?

Comment: You can also consider using the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) to pause/restart the timer when the user changes tabs/windows.

Comment: @apokryfos that would be quite helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Vlad nope. I have to design them :(

Comment: I suggest you to use express.js, you need to design simple crud api for your needs

Comment: @MohitChauhan keep in mind you're reinventing analytics in the frontend here, see my comment to the original post.

Comment: @Vlad I am still facing issues with how the payload should look like when we update the database?